# Deleting an SVN branch

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I created a branch of an SVN project called 'features', and now whenever I try to update said project, it brings with it a features folder, which contains another copy of the project from the branch.

Is there a way to remove the branch from the repository completely so that this doesn't happen any more?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Sure: `svn rm` the unwanted folder, and commit.

To avoid this situation in the future, I would follow the [recommended layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout) for SVN projects:

- Put your code in the
  `/someproject/trunk` folder (or just
  `/trunk` if you want to put only one
  project in the repository)
- Created branches as `/someproject/branches/somebranch`
- Put tags under `/someproject/tags`

Now when you check out a working copy, be sure to check out only `trunk` or some individual branch. **Don't** check everything out in one huge working copy containing all branches.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>Unless you know what you're doing, in which case you know how to create shallow working copies.</sub>

Answer (score 67):

For those using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), you can accomplish this by using the Repository Browser (it's labeled "Repo-browser" in the context menu.)

[image: context menu]

Find the branch folder you want to delete, right-click it, and select "Delete."

[image: deleting the folder]

Enter your commit message, and you're done.

[image: committing]

Comment: Do a SVN Update to remove folders from your disk (if not deleted before removing branch)

Answer (score 60):

Assuming this branch isn't an external or a symlink, removing the branch should be as simple as:

```
svn rm branches/< mybranch >

svn ci -m "message"
```

If you'd like to do this in the repository then update to remove it from your working copy you can do something like:

```
svn rm http://< myurl >/< myrepo >/branches/< mybranch >
```

Then run:

```
svn update
```

Comment: from [the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html): "Deleting a URL, however, is immediate, so you have to supply a log message [with -m]" so `svn rm -m message http://...` and no `update` required

Answer (score 14):

You can also delete the branch on the remote directly. Having done that, the next update will remove it from your working copy.

```
svn rm "^/reponame/branches/name_of_branch" -m "cleaning up old branch name_of_branch"
```

The `^` is short for the URL of the remote, as seen in 'svn info'. The double quotes are necessary on Windows command line, because `^` is a special character.

This command will also work if you have never checked out the branch.

Comment: I used this from a Mac and it worked well! When I tried the top answer I got the response "'/local/path/to/repo/branches/branch-name' is not a working copy" so presumably I'd never managed to check out the branch I made

Answer (score 4):

Command to delete a branch is as follows:

svn delete -m "<your message>" <branch url>

If you wish to not fetch/checkout the entire repo, execute the following command on your terminal:

1) get the absolute path of the directory that will contain your working copy
> pwd
2) Start svn code checkout
> svn checkout <branch url> <absolute path from point 1>

The above steps will get you the files inside the branch folder and not the entire folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the features folder just like any other in your checkout then commit the change.

To prevent this in the future I suggest you follow the naming conventions for SVN layout.

Either give each project a trunk, branches, tags folder when they are created.

```
svn
+ project1
  + trunk
    + src
    + etc...
  + branches
    + features
      + src
      + etc...
  + tags
+ project2
  + trunk
  + branches
  + tags
```

Answer (score 3):

From the working copy:

`svn rm branches/features`
`svn commit -m "delete stale feature branch"`