# i want to delete a release branch permenantely from my svn repository, i dont want to be it in my svn db

Tags: svn

please could anyone help me in deleting a release branch completely from my SVN repository, so that this will not be present in history..
thus requiring low disk space

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting an SVN Branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816626/deleting-an-svn-branch)

Comment: @MageXy  and two supporters- no, `svn rm` removes node only from HEAD, not from history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want remove some node without any traces in history, you have to

- Have full access to repository FS (not RW to repository)
- Create full dump of repo with `svnadmin dump`
- Remove unwanted branch from dump with `svndumpfilter`
- Load new clean dump into new empty repository with `svnadmin load`

Comment: Deleting my answer.  You've covered the same ground very nicely, and in fewer words to boot!

Comment: im getting the filterd branch againn

Answer (score -1):

You can just do `svn rm` to unwanted branch folder on your file system and do `commit`, thats all you have to do :), on server only delta may present which dont take much space.

Comment: hi tanku for quick reply....but when we do a reverse merge it will be available,but i dont want it to be in the repository totally...

Comment: Well technically it comeback by calculating deltas. Versioning is made for not loosing anything... but once you commit removed branch consider its gone.. you cant see it and your server space is also saved thats what you want ?